# Django: Modify Class Based View Context (with **kwargs)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I've a Function definition that works perfect, but I need to update to a Class Based View.

**function def:**

```
def ProdCatDetail(request, c_slug, product_slug):
    try:
        product = Product.objects.get(category__slug=c_slug, slug = product_slug)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return render(request, 'shop/product.html', {'product':product})
```

So far, I've read that to modify the context of a Class Based View (CBV) I need to overwrite the `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` in the CBV.

So, I've done this:

**Class Based View:**

```
class ProdCatDetailView(FormView):
    form_class = ProdCatDetailForm
    template_name = 'shop/product.html'
    success_url = 'shop/subir-arte'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product'] = Product.objects.get(category__slug=c_slug, slug = product_slug)
        return context
```

**How should I pass the arguments `c_slug`, `product_slug` to the get_context_data definition for this CBV to work as the Function definition?**

Comment: These are in `self.kwargs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class based view is, by the `.as_view` basically used as a function-based view. The positional and named parameters, are stored in `self.args`, and `self.kwargs` respectively, so we can use:

```
class ProdCatDetailView(FormView):

    # ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product'] = Product.objects.get(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['c_slug'],
            slug =self.kwargs['product_slug']
        )
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you! Very concise answer!